# UK postcode sector coordinates

Tags: postal-code

My research involves calculating the distances between centroids
of postcode sectors. In order to do this, I need to convert postcodes
into latitude/longitude coordinates in large batches. It is important that I am able to obtain centroids of postcode sectors, and not of the full postcodes.

Is it possible to obtain that information anywhere? The only data I
could find was on full postcodes.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to the community. What about the [weighted centroids](https://data.cdrc.ac.uk/dataset/cdrc-2011-population-weighted-centroids-gb) of each LSOA district. However, it takes into consideration the LSOA code. I am not sure that you can find straight from postcodes into coordinates since the ONS works with the Geographical codes.

Answer (score 1):

This data is not freely available, however, have a look at this project: http://www.freethepostcode.org/